# How to implement my own SelectionChangedEventHandler in c#

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, selectionchanged

I am working in silverlight and under a very strange situation that i need to implement my own SelectionChangedEventHandler handler function .The reason to do so is:

I have my situation like this :

```
    private static Grid GenerateList(Parameter param, int LoopCount, Grid g)
    {
        Grid childGrid = new Grid();
        ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
        childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
        childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
        childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);

        TextBlock txtblk1ShowStatus = new TextBlock();
        TextBlock txtblkLabel = new TextBlock();

        ListBox lines = new ListBox(); 
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();            
        scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        lines.ItemsSource = param.Component.Attributes.Items;
        scrollViewer.Content = lines; 
        Grid.SetColumn(scrollViewer, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(scrollViewer, LoopCount);
        childGrid.Children.Add(scrollViewer);

        lines.SelectedIndex = 0;
        lines.SelectedItem = param.Component.Attributes.Items;// This items contains 1000000,3 00000, and so on.
        lines.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(List_SelectionChanged);
       // lines.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(List_SelectionChanged(lines, txtblk1ShowStatus));
        lines.SelectedIndex = lines.Items.Count - 1;


        Grid.SetColumn(txtblk1ShowStatus, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(txtblk1ShowStatus, LoopCount);
        childGrid.Children.Add(txtblk1ShowStatus);
        g.Children.Add(childGrid);
        return (g);
    }
   static void List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("clist   _SelectionChanged1");  
      //The problem is line below because i am "lines" and "txtblk1ShowStatus" are not in the 
      //scope of this function and i cannot declare them globally.
        txtblk1ShowStatus.Text = lines[(sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex]; 
    }
```

Here you can see that i have no access of of "lines" and "txtblk1ShowStatus" in the `List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)` function. **And i cannot declate the button and list globally** because this function `GenerateList(...)` will be reused and it's just coded in c# (no xaml used).**Please let me know how to do that and also explain how to do that if you have another way to do but please explain your code with detail**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a lambda expression will help you solve your issues (you might need to edit it):

```
lines.SelectedIndex = 0;
lines.SelectedItem = param.Component.Attributes.Items;// This items contains 1000000,3 00000, and so on.

lines.SelectionChanged += (o,e) => {
    MessageBox.Show("clist   _SelectionChanged1");
    txtblk1ShowStatus.Text = lines.SelectedItem.ToString();
};

lines.SelectedIndex = lines.Items.Count - 1;
```

Comment: THANKS BUT : Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' corresponding lines[(o as ListBox).SelectedIndex];

Comment: You'll definitely need to edit that line. Is the listbox just "lines"? If so, you could probably use this instead:

`txtblk1ShowStatus.Text = lines[lines.SelectedIndex];`

Comment: Actually, upon re-evaluating the code, I'm not quite sure what's going on. Hopefully you can resolve this issue - best of luck to you!

Comment: Ok i done it :txtblk1ShowStatus.Text = lines.SelectedItem.ToString();

Comment: please change your code so that i willmark it as answer.

Comment: Why do you insist on using the 'lines' ListBox variable in the SelectionChanged handler?  The ListBox is passed as the first argument to the event handler.  Strange.